# php multiple dynamic calls

Tags: php, dynamic, methods, call

I know it's possible to call one method dynamically like

```
$function = 'foo';
$bar = new Bar();
$bar->$function();
```

What I'm trying to achieve is multiple call, like I receive an unknown amount of method ordered, and i have to call them from one object. I get for example `'foo', 'bar', 'bro'`, and I have to do dynamically `$object->foo()->bar()->bro()`.

Is it possible ? I know the call_user_func but I dont think it can solve this problem...
Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're doing it wrong if you think you need to do this.

Comment: I'm working with symfony, and using ajax to modify attributes. The problem is that my entities have children, and so on, and i'd like a general function

Comment: I refer you to my previous comment. :)

Comment: how would you do a general function if you have some objects like $main->setName() and some $main->getChild()->getFriend()->setHeight() for example ?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know what you are trying to achieve. I do know that you are breaking the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and that the future you will hate you for doing this as will anybody else that has to debug your code.

Comment: not breaking the law. Just trying to make the most general function I can in order to achieve a very specific goal, here access an attribute of an object of my forest of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the functions and apply them to each result:

```
$arr = array('foo','bar','bro');
$object = getTheObject();
$res = $object;
foreach($arr as $funcName){
    $res = $res->$funcName();
}
```

However this kind of code gives people nightmares since it's really not very clear what is going on. Consider using other approaches to do what you need.

Comment: sorry, the point is that I always have a set at the end, like $foo->getBar()->setBro(); and i cant make it work- edit - my bad, i did a simple mistake. Thanks a lot !